# [tensorflow],[bazel] Compile Tensorflow behind a HTTP/HTTPS Proxy - HTTP 502 Bad gateway

Tags: tensorflow, proxy, bazel

I know that this is no new questions, but I get lots of troubles when trying to compile tensorflow from the source. It seems like this is a "bazel behind proxy" matter.

- I compile on *Fedora28*
- I am using *bazel 0.17.2* (installed as a rpm from vbatts-bazel yum repository)
- I try to compile the current `master` from github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git

I work behind a HTTP/HTTPS proxy. The environment has http_proxy/https_proxy set (via `/etc/environment`, so everyone get the envvar). For tests I have set envvar in lowercase and uppercase. Using git/https, yum or wget through this proxy is OK since those envvar are set.

When compiling tensorflow (after the `./configure` step), I get an explicit HTTP error:

```
[user22@vm0 tensorflow]$ bazel build   --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz, https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz] to /home/user22/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user22/673c993ff8d0b73d5fcaf03ddf761476/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz: All mirrors are down: ***[Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway"]***
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz, https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz] to /home/user22/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user22/673c993ff8d0b73d5fcaf03ddf761476/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz: All mirrors are down: ***[Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway"]***
INFO: Elapsed time: 14.841s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

The issue is clearly this HTTP/1.1 502 error. I know other people had issues when using bazel behind a proxy, but I did find no reference to this HTTP error. Any idea about how I could fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

"502 Bad gateway" errors generally mean bazel asked the proxy to do something it was not allowed to do - in particular, bazel does not issue GET requests directly to the proxy, but will ask for a CONNECT command directly (seen with strace):

`sendto(220, "CONNECT mirror.bazel.build:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: Java/1.8.0_181\r\nHost: mirror.bazel.build\r\nAccept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2\r\nProxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n", 189, 0, NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>`

Your proxy configuration needs to be updated to allow CONNECT commands.

Alternatively, some [bazel github issues](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/587) indicate that you could look at the errors and download the content yourself, but that did not seem to end very well.

Comment: Actually, it seems like https_proxy / HTTPS_PROXY is simply ignored by bazel. Removing the envvar completely results in the same issue.

Comment: The bazel version in fedora 28 copr does use the variables, the most obvious thing to see is that it prints a warning if the proxy variables are set but no_proxy isn't set (saying it will set no_proxy itself) -- or just that you wouldn't get this error without a proxy set ;) But you need to be careful to stop the server everytime you change the variables, running a new bazel command won't update the proxy setting.

Comment: In fact, I have no_proxy (and NO_PROXY too) set in the environment, telling that localhost abd 127.0.0.1 + local ipaddr should not go through the proxy. Anyway, it behaves the same.